# I have a code for intraday strategy written in pine script but the trades are not been generated

Tags: tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="RSI Strategy", shorttitle="RSI Strat", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.1)

// Set the start date for backtesting (3 years ago from the current date)
start_year = year - 3
start_month = month
start_day = dayofmonth

// Set the end date for backtesting (current date)
end_year = year
end_month = month
end_day = dayofmonth

// Define a function to check if the current bar is within the backtesting period
in_backtest_period() =>
    year >= start_year and year <= end_year and month >= start_month and month <= end_month and dayofmonth >= start_day and dayofmonth <= end_day

// Inputs
rsi_length = input(7, title="RSI Length")
rsi_overbought = input(75, title="RSI Overbought")
rsi_oversold = input(25, title="RSI Oversold")
rsi_daily_min = input(30, title="RSI Daily Min")
rsi_daily_max = input(60, title="RSI Daily Max")
risk_reward_ratio = input(2, title="Risk Reward Ratio")

// Calculate RSI for 5-minute chart
rsi_5min = rsi(close, rsi_length)

// Calculate RSI for daily chart (higher timeframe)
rsi_daily = security("BINANCE:BTCUSDTPERP_D", "D", rsi(close, rsi_length))

// Calculate ATR on the 5-minute chart
atr_length = input(14, title="ATR Length")
atr = atr(atr_length)

// Define the end of the trading session 
session_end_hour = 16
session_end_minute = 0

// Check if it's the last bar of the trading session
is_last_bar_of_session = hour == session_end_hour and minute == session_end_minute

// Conditions
long_condition = crossover(rsi_5min, rsi_oversold) and (rsi_daily >= rsi_daily_min and rsi_daily <= rsi_daily_max)
short_condition = crossunder(rsi_5min, rsi_overbought) and (rsi_daily >= rsi_daily_min and rsi_daily <= rsi_daily_max)

// Entry
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=long_condition and in_backtest_period())
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=short_condition and in_backtest_period())

// Stop Loss and Take Profit
long_stop_loss = close - (2 * atr)
short_stop_loss = close + (2 * atr)

long_take_profit = close + (risk_reward_ratio * atr)
short_take_profit = close - (risk_reward_ratio * atr)

// Exit the trades if stop-loss or 1:2 profit is not met or at the end of the session
strategy.close("Exit Long", when=(long_condition and (not (long_take_profit >= high or long_stop_loss <= low) or na(long_take_profit) or na(long_stop_loss))) or is_last_bar_of_session)
strategy.close("Exit Short", when=(short_condition and (not (short_take_profit <= low or short_stop_loss >= high) or na(short_take_profit) or na(short_stop_loss))) or is_last_bar_of_session)

// Set stop loss levels
strategy.exit("Stop Loss Long", from_entry="Long", stop=long_stop_loss)
strategy.exit("Stop Loss Short", from_entry="Short", stop=short_stop_loss)
```

I am sure that conditions are matched, but still, no trades are been generated. The condition of long and short needs RSI details from 5-min and daily chart. ATR is used for stop-loss. If no exit condistion is matched, trades get close at the end of trading day.